# C++ - error with include <string>

Tags: c++, string, header, include

I am very new to c++ and am doing a tutorial. I have copied the tutorial exactly but on compiling get this error:

`'String file not found'`

for the line `#include <string>;`

Could someone tell me how to amend this?

Comment: Please post the code that you typed

Comment: Add the code that is giving you trouble.. Or link to the tutorial

Comment: Please try compiling a very small program (here is a [link](http://ideone.com/ZYFV1)) with your C++ compiler, and see if it gives you the same problem. If it does, please post the name and the version of your compiler, and the command line that you use to do the compile.

Comment: @Fiktik its a free online Stanford tutorial http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thanks for that - that one builds and runs fine

Comment: @MeltingDog It must be something else then. Could you post more code from the file that gives you trouble?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ok, so I changed the name of my file from .C to .cpp and this particular issue seems to have gone.

You seem to have found a solution, I'm adding this to clarify **why** this is happening. Some compilers integrated with IDEs treat `.c` files as C source code an `.cpp` (or `.cc`, `.c++`, etc.) as C++ code. As you compile a `.c` file, C++ support isn't included and a C compiler is used instead of a C++ one. And C doesn't have `<string>` (although it does have `<string.h>`, but that contains entirely different stuff).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your compiler isn't correctly or fully installed.  The compiler should be able to find its own headers without further effort on your part.

Comment: Yes it could be the compiler. I am using XCode version 4.3.2 whilst the tutorial is using version 2.5 or 3

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I changed the name of my file from .C to .cpp and this particular issue seems to have gone. However, I now get 3 Apple Mach-o Linker (Id) errors (?)

As this is different to the original questions I will close this and open a new one

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score -2):

check the location `c:/...../include`

If exist `string` file should reinstall compiler